# Reset origin of objects after file import (from Cinema 4D)

Tags: import, file-format

After import of a house model into Blender, all objects have a reference I don't know how to handle. I setup all to Meters and yes, I can scale it down and move manually and find a camera which works. But all models has values like -13000 but only as origin as it looks like. Every movement and rotation becomes horrible. How to fix the origin issue in Blender for file import?[image: Blender after import]?

It occurs on obj, dae, 3ds files and others.

[Download project](http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/BadOrigin.zip)

Comment: Can you edit your question and upload a .blend?

Comment: how to upload to giantcow?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/about/

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that it comes from single person. Anyway I uploaded the file. Is it possible that it an be the "parenting" or "transition" instead of origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I had the same problem when importing obj's exported from sketchup.

In order to fix it.

Select all the objects in object mode by pressing a.

Press (shift + ctrl + alt + c) or press space and type "set origin"

Chose either "origin to geometry" or "origin to centre of mass"

Answer (score 1):

After you bring *any* object into a new file, whether by appending from another blender file, or by importing a file from another format, the first actions you should take are to apply rotation, scale, and location. If the object's origin point is not where you want it, you can set the 3D cursor where you want the origin, and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to move the object origin to the 3D cursor.

Comment: sorry, does not work. I have uploaded the file.